# album tree deletion

Tags: database, mysql, treeview

i have following table

```
album_id    |    sub_album_id    |     name
sdf2342     |    0               |   family
a2243d      |    sdf2342         |   wife
23ods       |    sdf2342         |   jack
23jskd      |    0               |   places
```

i want to delete selected album with its all the sub_album and if there is more sub_album then delete them too.. so even sub_album can have a sub_album.. just like folder tree view.. there is no limit.

how can i delete all the sub albums of an album with the selected album.. doing it with one query.

Comment: In the example you give above there seems to be one album (sdf2342) which is a sub_album of two others... is this normal? If you delete 23ods and sdf2342, then a2243d is left with a bad pointer...

Comment: how deep (how many levels) can your album/subalbum hierarchies go?

Comment: there is no limit on hierarchies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanting to delete rows recursively from a hierarchy, there is some good background here:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score -1):

```
Delete from myTable 
where sub_album_id = 'sdf2342'
OR album_id = 'sdf2342'
```

EDIT 2/2/10:
I misunderstood the unlimited hierarchy,
Try this then:

```
MyLoop: LOOP
    DELETE FROM MyTable
    WHERE album_ID = 'sdf2342';

    IF SELECT count(*) where sub_album_id not in (select album_ID from MyTable) = 0 THEN LEAVE MyLoop END IF

    DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE sub_album_id not in (select album_ID from MyTable)

END LOOP MyLoop
```

My Syntax may be a little off because I'm trying to adapt a scripting language to stand alone SQL so you might have to work it. And this is going to blow up your processor on a large table unless it's indexed properly (need an index on sub_album_id and album_id at the least)

Comment: i need unlimited levels of hierarchical query

Comment: It should, I pulled most of the code out of the MySQL documentation.

Comment: just one last question, what if i wanted to delete all the media in same album or any sub album, what i would do.. table structure is easy.. just id, album_id, name

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you are asking. Would this be a different table than the one you posted?